# What is the function similar to mysql_affected_rows() in ZendDb

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db, zend-db-table

Following script gives us deleted rows count,

```
/* this should return the correct numbers of deleted records */
mysql_query('DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id < 10');
printf("Records deleted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

Is their any function similar to mysql_affected_rows() in ZendDb for getting deleted row count

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delete method returns number of rows deleted.

```
$deletedRows=$table->delete($query);
echo $deletedRows;
```